# how far a pointer can point to from it's starting point?

Tags: c++

i'm sending a string(sequence of characters) to a function in c++ and then the function 
would receive it in a pointer of char type.
but when i increase the pointer to reach each character it goes out of the string after 19th 
character and just points to somewhere else in my program.
here's the string i'm sending:

```
\xe1\x0c\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01
```

and here's my code:

```
char* request_process(char *request)
{
     for (int j = 0; j< 27; j++)
     {
        cout << (request[j] << 0) << "\n";
     }
 .
 .
 .    
 }
```

after "google" it goes wrong.
so what should i do to have it as (binary)"00000011" and then 'c'?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes wrong"?  (See also http://ideone.com/xoLJxU)

Comment: Your actual question is a red herring. The answer is platform-dependent, but you should be able to rely on the compiler to lay out your memory so that pointers cannot go out of bounds. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is almost certainly not the problem.  On the other
hand, `cout` is opened in text mode, and outputing non-printing
characters other than a few specially reserved (like `'\n'`) to
a file opened in text mode is undefined behavior.  In practice,
the implementation will probably let the characters through, but
who knows what effect they will have on the output device.

Comment: so what should i do to have it as (binary)"00000011" and then 'c'?

Comment: You shouldn't output "\x03" to a console device, period.